# Github dispatches workflow Invalid request

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I'm trying to trigger a workflow event in Github.

for some reason, I'm able to GET information about my organization repository workflow but can not use '**/dispatches**'

Work is based on: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

Here is the curl code:

```
curl -X POST \
         -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
         -H 'Authorization:token ${{ github.token }}' \
         'https://api.github.com/repos/[owner/org]/[repo]/actions/workflows/9999999/dispatches' \
         -d '{"event_type":"semantic-release"}'
```

Getting error:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
"message": "Invalid request.\n\nFor 'links/0/schema', nil is not an object.",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event"
```

Am I missing some basic information for this to work and trigger an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to call the GitHub API directly, try and use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/) (that you can [install first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=) to test locally).

You can also [use GitHub CLI in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows).

> GitHub CLI is preinstalled on all GitHub-hosted runners.
> For each step that uses GitHub CLI, you must set an environment variable called GITHUB_TOKEN to a token with the required scopes

It has a [`gh workflow run`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run), which does create a `workflow_dispatch` event for a given workflow.

Authenticates first ([`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), if you are doing a local test):

```bash
# authenticate against github.com by reading the token from a file
$ gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt
```

Examples:

```bash
# Run the workflow file 'triage.yml' at the remote's default branch
$ gh workflow run triage.yml

# Run the workflow file 'triage.yml' at a specified ref
$ gh workflow run triage.yml --ref my-branch

# Run the workflow file 'triage.yml' with command line inputs
$ gh workflow run triage.yml -f name=scully -f greeting=hello

# Run the workflow file 'triage.yml' with JSON via standard input
$ echo '{"name":"scully", "greeting":"hello"}' | gh workflow run triage.yml --json
```

In your case (GitHub Action):

```yaml
jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: gh workflow run triage.yml
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

---

As explained by [hanayama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19030730/hanayama) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406408/github-dispatches-workflow-invalid-request/72425326#comment127962352_72425326):

> Found out the secrets. `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't work, even with permissions edited for the entire workflow.
> Using a personal access token worked.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion indeed that would be a lot simpler. However, I tried running the "gh workflow run file.yml" in Github... goes green, but it doesn't show the workflow being triggered? any idea what could be the issue? token permissions?

should be triggered "on: workflow_dispatch:" and tested with "gh workflow list --all" to see if the cli works and I do get information on the workflows available.

Comment: Ok....found out the secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN doesn't work, even with permissions edited for the entire workflow. Using a personal access token worked...

Comment: @hanayama Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.